# 404 Received when getting delta

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-api

Beginning last weekend I began receiving `HTTP 404` responses when requesting a change list for a drive.

First I ensure the drive exists:

GET:

```
https://SOMEURL/sites/ASITENAME/_api/v2.0/drives/{id}/root
```

Response:

```json
{
  <SNIP>
    "id": "01JGC6XP56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-08-05T22:16:24Z",
    "name": "root",
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "b!n5c5t3PkRUiChm70bDc96e2yqnYltoJLq6IT5lxQYDZqi7UosRqoRa_3kgIU8qaV",
        "driveType": "documentLibrary"
    },
       "folder": {
        "childCount": 5
    },
    "root": {},
    "size": 0
}
```

Since that exists, I think I should be able to get a changelist for it.I try to get the changelist for this drive using the drive api.

Get:

```
https://SOMEURL/sites/ASITENAME/_api/v2.0/drives/{id}/root/view.delta?token=3;%234;%231;3;28b58b6a-1ab1-45a8-aff7-920214f2a695;636434930370000000;67434848;%23;%23;%230
```

Response:

```json
SPRequestGuid →b972249e-e00a-4000-8ed0-963ef7dba0e6
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found."
    }
}
```

Nothing is found, which feels wrong to me.  Checking [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_delta) it looks like the format has changed

Using the latest OneDrive documentation (`delta` instead of `view.delta`)

Get:

```
https://SOMEURL/sites/ASITENAME/_api/v2.0/drives/{id}/root/delta?token=3;%234;%231;3;28b58b6a-1ab1-45a8-aff7-920214f2a695;636434930370000000;67434848;%23;%23;%230
```

Response:

```json
SPRequestGuid →cf72249e-c0f7-4000-8ed0-97bf0cfaa584
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found."
    }
}
```

Using `/delta` with `token=latest`

GET:

```
https://SOMEURL/sites/ASITENAME/_api/v2.0/drives/{id}/root/delta?token=latest
```

Response:

```json
SPRequestGuid →eb72249e-e08d-4000-8ed0-94ad25d9e424
{
    "@odata.context": "https://SOMEURL/sites/ASITENAME/_api/v2.0/$metadata#items",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://SOMEURL/sites/ASITENAME/_api/v2.0/drives/{id}/root/view.delta(token='3;%234;%231;3;28b58b6a-1ab1-45a8-aff7-920214f2a695;636440196145030000;67696039;%23;%23;%230')",
    "@delta.token": "3;%234;%231;3;28b58b6a-1ab1-45a8-aff7-920214f2a695;636440196145030000;67696039;%23;%23;%230",
    "value": []
}
```

Let's try the Microsoft Graph API to see if there is any difference:

Using Microsoft Graph API:

GET: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{id}/root/delta`

RESPONSE:

```json
client-request-id →34978ae4-57cf-44c2-b5aa-05b8271ab070
request-id →34978ae4-57cf-44c2-b5aa-05b8271ab070
x-ms-ags-diagnostic →{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East US","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"003","Host":"AGSFE_IN_1","ADSiteName":"EST"}}
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "dc105a6d-8f37-4865-bede-cbd875729af7",
            "date": "2017-10-19T14:26:47"
        }
    }
}
```

I found [one public issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/288) which seems very similar to what I am experiencing.

My questions are:

1. Is `/view.delta` now considered deprecated?
2. If I can retrieve a drive, in one cases should I get a `404` when requesting the delta?
3. Why does using `?token=latest` return data but without it a `404` is returned?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a regression in behavior that's triggering for document libraries that have required columns or columns with validation formula. We're working on a fix and will get it deployed ASAP.

Comment: This issue should now be resolved - we apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the endpoint with the `OneDrive.` namespace (you can read [Direct Endpoint Differences: Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/direct-endpoint-differences#namespaces) for details).

So for the [Delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_delta) endpoint, rather than calling:

```
/_api/v2.0/drives/{id}/root/delta
```

Try calling

```
/_api/v2.0/drives/{id}/root/oneDrive.delta
```

I am however a little confused regarding the Microsoft Graph example. The syntax for your call (`/v1.0/drives/{id}/root/delta`) is correct.